# combining git and monotone

Tags: git, monotone

I need to work with an monotone repository. However I'm used to git and looking for way to push my changes into monotone (like `git-svn`). According to [monotone doc](http://www.monotone.ca/docs/Exporting-to-GIT.html) I can import the monotone repo into git. But do you know some good way to push my changes from git back to monotone?

Comment: I don't know of anything like that but if `Monotone` can import from `X` and `git` can export to `X`, then that is a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way I took was to mixing up git and monotone. Monotone maintains its internal information in directory `_MTN`. First I checked out the original monotone repository. After that I ran a `git init` in the new directory and imported all files. So I had one directory which is under monotone *and* git. In git I maintain one branch which is a pulling branch. It means only original changes from the monotone repository are imported. Furthermore there are a few other branches in git where I develop changes. In general this is a more dirty solution.

Lately I came across [tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor). This does exactly what I wanted. From the description in [Debian](http://debian.org/):

> migrate changesets between version control systems
>
> The tailor tool moves patches and changesets between different repositories, preserving as much information as possible. The repositories can be managed by different version control systems. Currently, ArX, Bazaar, Bazaar-NG, Codeville, CVS, Darcs, Git, Mercurial, Monotone, Subversion, and Tla are supported.
>
> While tailor is useful for one-time operation, when switching to a different
> version control system, it can also synchronise repositories on an ongoing
> basis. Changesets are either pulled one-way from a master repository, or
> migrated back and forth for full two-way synchronisation.